# Is there a way to invoke code insight on demand for record values in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

while writing queries if you press ctrl+space it  invokes code insight on demand and shows the possible column names for that table name mentioned in the query. Is there a similar way to get the list of possible record values for a particular column name(shortcut)?

```
select or from order_details;
```

here if I place the cursor after `or` and press ctrl+space it shows order_no,order_date etc.

```
select order_no= from order_details;
```

now is there a way to get the list of order_no(s) when I place the cursor after '=' in the query?

Comment: it is oracle sql developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

But you can ctrl+mouse hover + click on on ORDER_DETAILS in your FROM clause, and we'll open that table, then you can browse-peruse the values.

Comment: it gives the table details like created,owner etc, what I want is when I place the cursor next to '=' in  "order_no=<code insight>"   (and use some keyboard shortcut it should suggest me some order nos), may be order_no can have huge number of records ... say there is one more attribute called order type whose distinct values are 'A','B','C','D'.. I want to get the list of these distinct values.

Comment: I am not really sure whether this feature exists...I wish I could get one:)

Comment: click on the data tab, then you get the data too